# React app does not show favicon after build

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, favicon

I created my react app with create-react-app. 
When using npm start it works fine

[image]

But when I used npm run-script build and host it via 000webhostapp, the favicon does not show. Below is the code from index.html after build

```
<link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico"/>
```

[image]

When I call it directly
[image]

Even when open the index.html locally does not show the icon
[image]

Comment: does 'favicon.ico' location is okay? You have to provide absolute path.

Comment: I host via 000webhostapp, like this https://imgur.com/a/HWtV5rj and href="/favicon.ico"/. how can I use absolute path